# How to fix "2.4.7 Focus Visible" Element not highlighted in mac machine

Tags: html, accessibility

It gives me "2.4.7 Focus Visible" AA error in Mac when I check my site with [siteimprove](https://siteimprove.com/) chrome extension. Some times it works fine in windows systems some times it's not.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    a#login-as-guest:focus{ background-color: yellow; }

    a#login-as-guest-active:active{ background-color: yellow; }
  </style>
  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->

  <script type="text/javascript">        
    window.onload=function(){

    }    
   </script>    
</head>
<body>
  <a tabindex="0" id="login-as-guest">Cancel and browse as guest</a>    
<br />
<a id="login-as-guest-active">Active Cancel and browse as guest</a>      
  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "t2hbS"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's already running in my server "https://myappdemo.com/focus/test.html"

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample just changes the focus background color and your [demo link](https://myappdemo.com/focus/test.html) just sets the focus text color.  A typical focus indicator is an outline border, which is provided by default by most (all?) browsers, but your color changes are sufficient to show a focus too.  In fact, since you are only changing `:focus{background-color}` and `a{color}`, respectively in the two examples, you will get your color change **and** the browser's default focus border.

I don't see why siteimprove is flagging it.  Can you post the error siteimprove is claiming and all relevant info it's complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that user interface elements, that can receive keyboard focus, are highlighted on focus.

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: green;
}
```